# xcode(iPhone)のカメラアプリのシャッターUIの透明化

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

iPhoneのカメラアプリのシャッターUIの透明化方法について、
教えてください。

下記、参考画像のように、作成したカメラアプリだとシャッターUIの
上下が黒帯が表示されてしまうのですが、この部分を透明にしたいです。
（透明にしているカメラアプリがあったので、できると思いまして）

シャッターUIの上下の黒帯を透明にする、サンプルプログラムのサイトや
プログラムをご存知の人がいましたら、教えていただけると助かりますm(_ _)m

下記サイトにあるカメラアプリを実現したいと思っております

↓カメラアプリの撮影ボタンバーを透明化する事が出来るカメラアプリ
http://iphonedatu.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-249.html

カメラアプリのプログラムは、下記サンプルプログラムをほぼ使用しております。

↓カメラアプリのサンプルプログラム
http://iphone.moo.jp/app/?p=213

[補足]
このサンプルプログラムでは、シャッターUIの上下の黒帯が半透明になっているのですが
自作のプログラムにベーストしたら、シャッターUIの上下の黒帯の半透明処理は、
再現しませんでした。
上記サンプルプログラムのこの部分が、シャッターUIの上下の黒帯が半透明の指示をしている
など、もし分かる方がいましたら教えて頂けると幸いです

▼シャッターUIの上下黒帯の参考イメージ
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

▼プログラム抜粋

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
}

-(IBAction)openCamera
{
    if( [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hk.png"]];
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = imageView;      
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: すでに投稿した回答の内容の裏付けとして質問があります。帯が半透明で表示された時は、アプリそのものが4インチ以上の画面に非対応で、シャッターUIは画面上端ではなく撮影プレビューの上端にありませんでしたか？

Comment: ご質問ありがとうございます。
サンプルプログラムを確認したところ、widht320,height460なので、4インチ非対応ですね。シャッターボタンは、サンプルプログラムでは合成画像に隠れて見えませんが、下部になります

Comment: 「透明にしているカメラアプリがあったので、できると思いまして」が脱獄アプリだと話が変わります。それも後出しで書かれるようでは。先の回答のコードの機能も理解できて‌​いないようですが、示されたコードの意味をじぶんで調べて理解した上で話を進めるのが最低限の学習行動だと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご気分を害したら申し訳ないです。
頂いたコードは、撮影した画像をカメラロールに保存するメソッドでしょうか。
実現したいことは、撮影ボタンバーを透明化できなくても、カスタマイズしたい(黒帯の表示スペースを小さくしたい)ということなのですが、本質問とは変わっていますので、別途文面を整理して質問を出したいと思います。

Comment: おっしゃる通り、新しく質問し直したほうがいいですね。問題解決用のサンプルがUIImagePickerController（以下、IPC）、実現例が純正カメラアプリ‌​の外観をカスタマイズする脱獄アプリと、解決策の条件が乱れてます。／結論だけいうと、撮影ボタンバー（正式にはカメラUIとかカメラコントロールとか呼びます）は元々半透‌​明で、色やサイズの変更はできません。が非表示にはできます。でIPCにはカスタムビューを重ねて表示できるので、カメラUIを自作することで期待するUIに似せることがで‌​きるかもしれません。新しい質問をするときは、「IPCのカスタマイズまたはカメラUIの自作」を焦点にして、通常のカメラUIを透明にしたような状態を作りたいと質問して‌​くれると分かりやすいかと思います。

Comment: 遅くなってすみません。新しい質問のアドバイスまで、ありがとうございます。サンプルプログラム実行しました。カメラUI、自作することができるのですね。全部自作すると大変そうですね^^;IPCのプログラムを調べてみたいと思います

Answer (score 2):

そのUIViewControllerに以下のメソッドを加えて実際に写真を保存してみてください。

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

もし、あなたが黒帯と言っているものの背面もカメラの撮影領域であるなら、その部分も写真として保存されるはずですが、見えている部分のみの画像が保存されたならば、半透明になっていないのではなく、ただ単に帯の後ろそのものが黒だと考えられます。

---

**追記** : カメラUIのカスタマイズについて

参考画面

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

カメラUIを自作することでこのようにしていくことは可能ですが、撮影プレビューは上寄せに表示されますし、「撮影」「キャンセル」「モード切替」など、各種処理もボタンとコードを結びつけて自作していく必要があります。

ViewController.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)openCamera:(id)sender {

  BOOL cameraIsAvailable = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

  if(cameraIsAvailable){

    if (!self.imagePickerController) {

      self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
      self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
      self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: self.imagePickerController.sourceType];
      self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
      self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
      self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

      UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
      button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 120, 44);
      button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
      button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
      button.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
      [button setTitleColor: [UIColor whiteColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
      [button setTitle: @"Capture" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
      [button addTarget: self action: @selector(didTapCaptureButton:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = button;
    }

    [self presentViewController: self.imagePickerController animated: YES completion: nil];
  }
}

- (void)didTapCaptureButton:(UIButton *)button {

  [self.imagePickerController takePicture];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  UIImage *originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(originalImage, self, @selector(didCompleteSaveImage:error:contextInfo:), nil);
}

- (void)didCompleteSaveImage:(UIImage *)image error:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {

  if (error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    return;
  }

  [self.imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:^{

    NSLog(@"Saved a picture.");
    self.imagePickerController = nil;
  }];
}

@end
```

Comment: コメントとサンプルプログラムありがとうございます！ 撮影ボタンバーの黒帯の所が写真に保存されました。 頂いたプログラムを実装したのですが、撮影ボタンバーの黒帯を透明化はしませんでした。 説明が悪くてすみません。
下記サイトにあるカメラアプリを実現したいと思っております ↓カメラアプリの撮影ボタンバーを透明化する事が出来ます
http://iphonedatu.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-249.html 上記プログラムは書いてないので、分かりましたら教えていただけると助かりますm(_ _)m